# Problem issues about publishing a bot from Visual Studio 2017 to Azure App Services, no errors but doesn't work at all

Tags: c#, botframework

I have an application made in bot framework that I published in Azure, in the publication I took into account all the parameters of previous configurations that must be done (register the bot in botframework, create an MS app ID, password and key, integrate in the app .settings the respective ID-password and Key, re-publish it, configuration of the URL when adding "/ api / messages", etc)

but despite following everything at face value when going to do a test in the Test Web Chat of the web application in Azure, it remains loaded and does not respond.

I have done tests in the Bot Framework Emulator and it works without any problem

What could be happening in the Azure Web App?

I followed these MS guides:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs

[Azure Infinite web app Loading Screen](https://drive.google.com/open?id=160yDFhX5vljJ6hDxSAqZUmVCNe_YiD7-)

if need for more info or code info, please ask and i post it

Comment: Is web chat enabled on the 'channels' screen?

Comment: I am doing tests within the Web Chat Test of the Web App Bot application, therefore we are not using the channels as such and if it were used, I would also have the same error

Comment: Does your bot file have a production endpoint?

Comment: Is your bot working locally? Is it based off of one of the samples? If you view your bot's files at `https://<your-bot>.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/`, is your `.bot` file there? Does it have a `production` endpoint? Is everything correct in your `.bot` file and `appsettings.json`? If you can provide your appId, I can help troubleshoot further.

Regarding @stuartd's comment, in your Web App Bot resource, click "Channels" and then look at the "Issues" under "Web Chat"

Comment: @renzo.barrios1407 Were you able to get things working?

Comment: @mdrichardson yes, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an arduous search and tests, I discovered that the BotFramework that I have, is programmed in version V3 and since December is already version V4, then look at instructions how to do the deployment and manage to do it !!! thank you all for your advice, I leave the link where you guide me:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

Thanks, i will update my answer later for more info